# Missing return in a function Swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error `Missing return in a function expected to return "User"` for this code:

```
var winner : User? {

    if player1TotalScore > player2TotalScore {
        return player1

    } else if player1TotalScore == player2TotalScore {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The most curious thing about this is that I do basically the same thing a few lines up:

```
var opponent : User! {
    if player1.isEqual(User.currentUser()) {
        return player2
    } else {
        return player1
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the first bit of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if `player1TotalScore` is less than `player2TotalScore`. It falls through both `if` conditions and has no return value. You have to handle every case, and you're missing one here. That's why the `else` works, it handles both the `==` and the `<` cases.

Answer (score 0):

In case player1TotalScore < player2TotalScore your code will not return any value.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the last `else` statement

```
var winner : User? {

    if player1TotalScore > player2TotalScore {
        return player1

    } else if player1TotalScore == player2TotalScore {
        return nil
    } else {
        /// return player2 ?
    }
}
```

Without the last `else` winner returns nothing

Hope this helps you !